# Google Script sort 2D Array by any column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had a asked an earlier question about retrieving records from a database, here: [Retrieving Records from a Google Sheet with Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872861/retrieving-records-from-a-google-sheet-with-google-script)

I'm fairly comfortable with manipulating arrays and creating my own sorting algorithms, but I want to use the existing `Array.sort()` method to organize the data because of its speed. I'm finding that I can easily use this to sort a 2D array by the first column of data, but I can't find the syntax to sort on a different column of data, other than the first.

The closest that I've found is this: [Google Apps Script Additional Sorting Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859024/google-apps-script-aditional-sorting-rules). However, these inputs haven't worked for me. Here is what I get for the following code, for my array, tableData:

```
tableData.sort([{ column: 1}]);
```

=>TypeError: (class)@4dde8e64 is not a function, it is object. (line 49, file "sortTablebyCol")

```
tableData.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
```

=> TypeError: (class)@4d89c26e is not a function, it is object. (line 50, file "sortTablebyCol")

What is the proper syntax for choosing which column of data to sort on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method can have a function argument to choose on what part you want to sort. Code goes like this :

```
    array.sort(function(x,y){
      var xp = x[3];
      var yp = y[3];
// in this example I used the 4th column... 
      return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

---

### EDIT

Following your comment, here is a small demo function that should help to understand how this works.

Instead of using short form if/else condition I used the traditional form and splitted it in 3 lines to make it easier to understand.

```
function demo(){
  // using a full sheet as array source
  var array = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log('Unsorted array = '+array);
  array.sort(function(x,y){
// in this example I used the 4th column... 
    var compareArgumentA = x[3];
    var compareArgumentB = y[3];
    // eventually do something with these 2 variables, for example Number(x[0]) and Number(y[0]) would do the comparison on numeric values of first column in the array (index0) 
    // another example x[0].toLowerCase() and y[0].toLowerCase() would do the comparison without taking care of letterCase...
    Logger.log('compareArgumentA = '+compareArgumentA+' and compareArgumentB = '+compareArgumentB);
    var result = 0;// initialize return value and then do the comparison : 3 cases
    if(compareArgumentA == compareArgumentB ){return result }; // if equal return 0
    if(compareArgumentA < compareArgumentB ){result = -1 ; return result }; // if A<B return -1 (you can change this of course and invert the sort order)
    if(compareArgumentA > compareArgumentB ){result = 1 ; return result }; // if a>B return 1
    }
            );
  Logger.log('\n\n\nSorted array = '+array);
}
```

I added a couple of Logger.log to check starting, intermediate and final values. Try this in a spreadsheet.

Hoping this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Serge. I looked further into the sheet.getrange(), range.sort() and range.getvalues() documentation as well as the documentation link that you provided. I realized that the difference between what I was doing and what the documentation suggests is shown as below: //What I was originally doing, that gives an error =>
  var tableData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  tableData.sort(1);
  //What actually works =>
  var tableDataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  tableDataRange.sort(1);

Comment: Why would the sort function be able to handle the range and not the array of its values? Do you have any insight to this?

Comment: The sort method you refer to is a [range method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)), an array is a JavaScript object and has only JavaScript methods... the example I show is pure JavaScript, you can actually do more with it...

Comment: Thank you, Serge. That makes sense. I didn't understand that the sort method was a method of the Range class, as you said. Thank you for the code snippet, it works perfectly for me, even though I don't quite understand the syntax of it yet. I will dig into this.

Comment: Yes, it's worth studying that... I learned it some time ago and now I use it all the time ;-) - thanks for accepting (also)

Comment: I added a small demo code to show more precisely how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems if instead of using .getValues , you restrict to .getDataRange then perhaps your original sort code "tableData.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);" can work if you avoid the square bracket.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C7");

// Sorts by the values in the first column (A)
range.sort(1);

// Sorts by the values in the second column (B)
range.sort(2);

// Sorts descending by column B
range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
```

I found this in [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a library like underscore.js which has a lot of useful functions to manipulate collections, arrays, map/reduce, sorting etc... Works without a glitch with Google Apps Script. That's the first library I add to any project I start on GAP.