# Auto sort script for google sheets by 2 columns

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script

I have multiple sheets that need sorting and they need to be sorted by different columns.  This is the script I'm currently running:

```
function onEdit(){
  var sheetNames = ["General Clerk Onboarding Tracker"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort([{column: 10, ascending: true}]);
  });
}
```

I want to add another range sort column so it'll sort by column 10 first, THEN by column 17.  I can't seem to get it to auto-sort 2 columns.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think you would just be looking to modify your last line as follows:

```
    range.sort([{column: 10, ascending: true}, {column: 17, ascending: true}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help [Additional Sorting Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859024/google-apps-script-aditional-sorting-rules) have a look and if not I will have a further look into it for you.
Good Luck :)

Comment: I saw that one but I wasn't sure how to add it to the script I already have in place.  I would need some assistance (I'm a serious Novice at this)